# Python how to add char to a string every x position

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns a string with every xth character followed by an asterisk.

string_chunks("once upon a time, in a land far far away, 5)

should return:

```
'O*once u*pon a* time*, in a lan*d far far* away*'
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def string_chunk(string, x):
    strings = ""
    y = x
    for char in string:
        strings += string[y-x:y] + "*"
        y += x
    return strings



print string_chunk("summer is really cool", 5)
```

This is what I get. I dont want the added asterisks at the end.

```
"summe*r is *reall*y coo*l*****************"
```

Comment: sorry read again @MattDMo

Comment: Think about using the length of the string in some error-checking calculations...

Comment: Also, try printing the values of your various variables each time through your loop, so you can see what's going on.

Comment: The specified `return` sample doesn't have every 5th character followed by an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension and then join tha list with an asterisk:

```
astr = 'this is an example string'
'*'.join([astr[j*5:j*5+5] for j in xrange(len(astr)/5+1)])
## 'this *is an* exam*ple s*tring*'

astr = 'this is an example string too'
'*'.join([astr[j*5:j*5+5] for j in xrange(len(astr)/5+1)])
## 'this *is an* exam*ple s*tring* too'
```